# Don't show background of JPEG while it is loading in the browser

Tags: html, css

I have an image that may load slowly for some users of my website, so I would like to have a reasonable fallback placeholder while it is loading. I found the [gradify library](https://github.com/QueraTeam/gradify), which can create a CSV gradient that matches the image.

Before the image has begun loading, the background gradient is shown. However, once the image starts to load, it is replaced with a white background and then loads in from top to bottom.

(You can see this by activating throttling in the browser dev tools when loading the image.)

Is it possible, without JavaScript, to not start showing the image until it is completely downloaded?

I think I could partially alleviate this by changing to an interlaced/progressive image, but I'm still interested in the answer to the question :)

```css
body {
  /* just centering stuff, not really part of the question */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* bg so you can see the effect */
  background: radial-gradient(circle, #222 0%, #aaa 100%);
}

img {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  border: 5px solid purple;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;

  /* generated by gradify */
  background-color: rgb(72,148,223);
  background-image: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(72,148,223,1) 0%, rgba(72,148,223,0) 100%),linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(49,98,174,1) 0%, rgba(49,98,174,0) 100%),linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(114,129,143,1) 0%, rgba(114,129,143,0) 100%),linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(43,48,71,1) 0%, rgba(43,48,71,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="https://jpeg.org/images/about.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You won't be able to do that without JavaScript. Is that an option?

Comment: It's an option, but I'd rather not (not for any really good reason though). I think going the progressive image route might be the right choice.